# Есть ли какие то ограничения на функции внешних библиотек?

Tags: android

Какие правила создания android module(lib) есть? в модуль кладут только логику или можно все класть activity, fragments и  view? на пример можно ли моделе создать navigation drawer, и использовать его во всех своих проектах?

Comment: Если речь идет не о модели, как о единице архитектуры приложения, а о модуле, как библиотека, то можно, более того - `NavigationDrawer` уже [сделали](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer).

Comment: activity и fragment можно?

Comment: Библиотекой может быть все, что угодно, что будет использоваться многократно. В пределах разумного.

Comment: у меня есть модель работа с серверной частью, мне надо  в модель набросать  ND  и пару экранов и карту и т.д.  И при создания нового проекта я подключаю этот модель, изменяю пару  view,  цвет  и т.д.  и проект готов Вот что я хочу, это реально

Comment: модель (структура данных) или модуль (библиотека)?

Comment: структура данных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку подключаемая библиотека всего лишь расширение видимости пакетов, то она может иметь практически любое содержание, которое используется многократно без серьезных изменений: в том числе шаблоны активити или фрагментов, от которых потом можно отнаследоваться для незначительного изменения функциональности или использовать "как есть", какие то "собранные" сложные виджеты, вроде `NavigationDrawer`или `SearchView` с автодобавлением, кастомные виджеты, классы работы с БД или сетью, какие то утилиты, расчитывающие специфичные значения.
Можно даже сделать библиотеку, состоящую только из ресурсов - например, пака иконок или шрифтов .. или типовых разметок экранов.